# SQL Query to FILTER customers who have purchased same product multiple times with a quantity greater than 5

Tags: sql, database, count, subquery

I have a table `Customer_Order_Data` with these columns:

1. customer_id
2. order_id
3. product_id
4. quantity

I want to find the customers who have purchased the same product (`product_id`) multiple times with a `quantity > 5`.

Let's say I have the following data -

| Order_id | Customer_id | product_id | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | ABCD | B019 | 2 |
| 00002 | ABCD | B019 | 6 |
| 00003 | EFGH | B018 | 8 |
| 00004 | ABCD | B019 | 7 |
| 00005 | EFGH | B018 | 1 |
| 00006 | IJKL | B017 | 9 |
| 00007 | ABCD | B015 | 10 |

I want to filter out the customers who have purchased same product multiple times where `quantity  > 5`.
Now `Customer EFGH` has purchased `product B018` twice but do not have qauntity purchased greater than 5 in both cases, so it should not be displayed in result.

Result expected -

| Order_id | Customer_id | product_id | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | ABCD | B019 | 2 |
| 00002 | ABCD | B019 | 6 |
| 00004 | ABCD | B019 | 7 |

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the issue you have? Please, provide any code you already have for someone could correct you

Comment: You **just asked** this 5 hours ago - and got answers - please **DO NOT** repost the same question over and over again

Comment: @marc_s - The older question was showing as closed. So, posted again. Also, this is very first question for me. Would keep in mind. Thanks.

Comment: Yes - and it was closed **for a reson**: *This question needs details or clarity. * - you've reposted the **same question** without providing any shred of additional details or clarity...... **IF** you want to repost - then you **at least** need to read why the first question was closed - and **do something about it** ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses a subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where (
    select count(*) 
    from mytable t1 
    where 
        t1.customer_id = t.customer_id 
        and t1.product_id = t.product_id 
        and t1.quantity > 5
) > 1
```

The idea is to count how many rows in the table have the same customer and product, and a quantity greater than 5.

You can also use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(case when quantity > 5 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by customer_id, product_id) as cnt
    from mytable t
) t
where cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IN clause as follows:

```
Select * from your_table
Where (customer_id, product_id) IN 
(Select customer_id, product_id
  From your_table t
 Where quantity > 5
Group by customer_id, product_id
Having count(1) > 1)
```